# How do I make this method thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, guava

I want `getData()` to be idempotent, if that's the right word. Every call to it, whether it's from two different threads, concurrently, serially to return the same value.
My main issue is that two threads call `MyMap.getData()` and I was noticing that the returned map was inconsistent -- refer to the block of code now `l.lock()`'ed -- since it was likely mutated by two threads or the `puts` and `gets` of the underlying map wasn't synced. I was wondering if this is now thread-safe and if not, how to make it bullet-proof. The method `getData` basically 
Here's some pseudo-java-guava code:

```
public class MyMap extends Map {

  final Lock l = new ReentrantLock();

  public Table<S, I, F> getData(Iterable<S> ss, Iterable<B> bs) {

    final Table<S, I, F> t = HashBasedTable.create();
    final ImmutableSet.Builder<B> builder = ImmutableSet.builder();
    for (B b : bs) {
      builder.add(b)
    }
    final ImmutableSet<B> finalBs = builder.build();

    for (A a : as) {
      final ImmutableTable<I, I, F> im = get(a);
      l.lock();
      try {
        if (im == null) {
          final Table<I, I, F> mutableT = HashBasedTable.create()
          ... populate table ...
          put(a, ImmutableTable.copyOf(mutableT);
        }
      } finally {
        l.unlock();      
      }

      for (Map.Entry<I, I, F> entry : im) {
        final A a = ... some simple transform of key ...
        for (Map.Entry<I, F> entry2 : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
           if (finalBs.contains(entry.B) {
             t.put(a, entry.B, entry.C) 
           }
        }
      }

    }

    return ImmutableTable.copyOf(t); 

  }


}
```

Comment: Lock outside the for-loop? What part requires thread-safety?

Comment: I'm not really following the code.  Your `get()` method seems to be a "merge" rather than a "get".  Stuff like "query database" and some class names I don't recognize don't help.  Thread safety depends on many correct details.  Can you explain your intentions better?

Comment: @Bubletan That's what I'm asking.

Comment: @markspace I'll update my post for clarity.

Comment: Nothing "requires" thread safety.  You just mark your class as "not thread safe" and let some one else worry about it.  It's how you use an object that makes it thread safe, and we don't see how you are using these classes.

Comment: @markspace There is a conventional meaning for "thread safe class."  A class is thread-safe if there's no way to make it break the guarantees that are promised in its API contract by calling its methods from different threads.  But of course, the fact that an individual _class_ is thread safe does not guarantee the thread-safety of the application or higher-level class that uses it.

Comment: I've updated the post for clarity.

Comment: By that definition, only immutable objects in Java are thread safe.  So "thread safe" really means a lot of different things, which causes problems in and of itself.  I agree that regardless it's possible for an application to use classes incorrectly.

Comment: @markspace, `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is one example of a class that is both mutable and thread-safe:  No matter how many threads make overlapped calls to its methods; every item that you put in to it eventually will come out, exactly once, A will come out before B if A went in before B.,...  The size() is less reliable than other queues, but the Javadoc warns you about that, so still "thread-safe."  All of its other guarantees will hold.  But if your application requires A to come out before B, then you'll need higher-level synchronization to insure that A goes in before B.